infinite redirects when keycloak login happens and redirects to app page
when going with development keycloak instance on docker its working fine but when working with prod settings keycloak instance on docker it goes into infinite redirects when it comes to app page?
Tried checking state changes in the react app but no progress.

So, in my keyclaok init config,
const authenticated = await kc.init({
    onLoad: 'login-required',
    checkLoginIframe: false,
    pkceMethod: 'S256',
});

Changed the check login frame to false and then it stopped those redirects.
